# Rust function signature

Tags: rust, rust-axum

From Axum Example: [https://github.com/tokio-rs/axum/examples/query-params-with-empty-strings/src/main.rs#L23-L25](https://github.com/tokio-rs/axum/blob/827140f0d788a0ac3b73faec931e18c6b915e059/examples/query-params-with-empty-strings/src/main.rs#L23-L25)

```rust
async fn handler(Query(params): Query<Params>) -> String {
    format!("{:?}", params)
}
```

What is the name of the signature pattern when `Query(params)` is used on param left?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What is the name of the signature pattern when Query(params) is used on param left?

It's literally just a pattern (as in pattern-matching): in Rust, a *binding* (a parameter, or the left-hand side of a `let`, or the left hand side of a `for`) can be a pattern as long as it's infallible (/ irrefutable*). `match` and friends are necessary for refutable patterns (patterns which can fail, because they only match a subset of all possible values).

Some languages call this *destructuring* but Rust doesn't make a difference.

For Axum, it's just a convenient way of accessing the contents of the query parameter (or other extractors), you could also write this as:

```rust
async fn handler(query: Query<Params>) -> String {
    format!("{:?}", query.0)
}
```

or

```rust
async fn handler(query: Query<Params>) -> String {
    let Query(params) = query;
    format!("{:?}", params)
}
```